# Spring MVC 404 Error Page

Tags: java, spring

I have Global exception handler defined using ControllerAdvice, for IOException, I am returning 404.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
public void handleIOException(){
    logger.error("IOException");
    //returning 404 error code
}
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resources/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I am deliberately throwing IOException in a controller, but it's not using the 404 error page. If I give some random URL, the 404 page is getting used.

I am confused why it's not working with exception handler.

Comment: could you post the relevant parts of your web.xml file? (the spring mvc configuration)

Comment: Why do you think the IOException will end up displaying `/resources/404.jsp`? The response will be completed when your handler returns.

Comment: @Bart when spring container will throw 404 error code, servlet container will look at the error page configuration in web.xml and send the configured page as response. Am I missing something here?
updated post with web.xml content.

Comment: Make sure you have <mvc:annotation-driven/>  in spring xml. <context:annotation-config /> will not load ControllerAdvice . did you got logs mentioned in your handler method

Comment: Yes, the logs in handleIOException method are getting printed.

Comment: No it will not. The return value of you exception handler will result in a empty `ModelAndView` and the response will be empty as well. If you want to page the display you will need to return a `String` or `ModelAndView` that will denote your view name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine now, after I deleted the project from tomcat webapps and did a fresh deploy. May be some issues with tomcat hot deployment.

So when my controller is throwing 404 error, tomcat container is looking at the error-page configured for it and sending configured error-page as response.